# iText 7 absolute position text appears only on last page

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I am trying to add text at an absolute position but the text appears only on the last page with my code.

```
   TextEventHandler textHandler = new TextEventHandler(doc);
        pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, textHandler);


    public class TextEventHandler implements IEventHandler {
        protected Document doc;

        public TextEventHandler(Document pdfDoc) {
            this.doc = pdfDoc;
        }

        public void handleEvent(Event event) {


        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("this is the text");
            p.setFixedPosition(100,200, 50);
            p.setFontColor(color);
            p.setFont(font);
            p.setBold();
            p.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
            p.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
            p.setHeight(iV.textHeight);
         doc.add(p);
    }
    }
```

Comment: When exactly do you call `pdfDoc.addEventHandler`?

Comment: I have tried to add pdfDoc.addEventHandler at a number of places but all have the same effect. If there is only 1 page it works fine otherwise it adds to the last page. Watermark etc works fine on every page.

Comment: Have you tried to register this for the start of page?

Comment: Should I be using a canvas here.

Comment: *"Should I be using a canvas here"* - Yes, considering the examples [here](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/page-events-for-headers-and-footers).